# Get ImageView id inside multiple LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, picasso

I am using a custom Listview containing Images and Buttons.

my **listview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout">

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am dealing with 3 LinearLayouts here.

my **button_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/parent"
>

   <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"  android:id="@+id/child1"
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listarray"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:gravity="center"  android:id="@+id/child2">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/one"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/two"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />
</LinearLayout>
```

**adapter code**

tweetArray containing my list.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.button_view, R.id.listarray, tweetArray);
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

**Issue :** My problem is that how can i get id of `ImageView`.

**Tried :** I have tried to get in simple way as

```
 ImageView user_picture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
 Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg).into(user_picture);
```

But this is showing ***error* : *Target must not be null***.

Do you have any Idea...?

Comment: If that code is in your `Adapter`, you need to call `findViewById()` on the `View` you're inflating for the list item.

Comment: how to do that @MikeM.

Comment: You need to post the code for your `Adapter`.

Comment: downvoters can you share the reason too please. that might be helpfull.

Comment: That's not how you create a `ListView` with a custom item layout. You need to implement a custom `Adapter` class. Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view).

Comment: please read the documentation @Atula  [ListView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)  [Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html)     Tutorials:  [Tutorial 1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_list_view.htm)  [tutorial 2](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

Comment: thanks @SaravInfern for the links. but they not helpful for now.

Comment: @Mike M can you share any alternative to deal with this issue.

Comment: Any alternative would be even more complicated and involved. That's the basics for a custom `ListView`.

Answer (score -1):

try to customize your adapter 
please check the link for adapter

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Link only answers are [not considered good practise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7515/why-is-linking-bad) on Stack Overflow. The question "answer" should actually contain an answer or at very least a summary of the content and how it pertains to the question.

Comment: getting null as result